How to Create a Word Template with a Dynamic Repeated Table and Child Table for Power Automate?
I am using Power Automate with the Word Business connector to create a Word template and convert it into a PDF. My Word template includes:
A dynamic repeated table where rows are populated dynamically based on input data.
A child table that needs to be placed at the end of the repeated table, populated with corresponding data.
I am designing this template using the Developer tab in Word and content controls. The final document should resemble the attached image, where:
The main table dynamically repeats rows for each dataset.
A secondary (child) table appears at the end of the main table, summarizing additional details.
I need guidance on:
How to structure the Word template to include both the repeated table and the child table.
Updating values dynamically in this format using Power Automate.
Any help, examples, or documentation would be greatly appreciated!
Attached: Screenshot of the required document format.
Source code :word tempalte


Cool, how does it go? You just told us what you want to achieve, but didn't post any code! Can we please get a [mcve]?

Yes sure. I have tried in word format I will attach my template here..Hope you can help more from there
